# how to get updated attribute value using selenium

Tags: java, html, selenium, attributes

I have few tabs and each tabs has the below attribute which has true or false value to identify weather the tab is selected or not. if the tab is selected value of the attribute will be true if not selected then false.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='FILLED']"));

String tab_status =     returnAttribute(element, "aria-pressed");

    System.out.println(tab_status);
```

for this  i have a tab called "filled" and it was not selected at first, so i get the attribute values as false. but then i have a code to click the tab.

```
PerformAction.FuncClick(team.getfilled_tab());
```

when i do manually, after the click manually i can see the attribute value has changed to true, but when u try the above code to retrieve the attribute value using selenium, i am still getting attribute value as false, is that because when i run pragmatically the page is not refreshing ?

i even tried below code for refreshing page after clicking the tab. but still attribute value is returning as false. can someone suggest why is it happening?

```
CL.GetDriver().navigate().refresh();
```

complete function is giving below

```
public void filter_tab_function() throws InterruptedException, IOException {


    PerformAction.FuncClick(team.getfilled_tab());



    Thread.sleep(2000);

    CL.GetDriver().navigate().refresh();

    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='FILLED']"));

    String tab_status =     returnAttribute(element, "aria-pressed");

        System.out.println(tab_status);



}
```

Comment: could you paste the full code, it might go wrong if you findElement BEFORE clicking the tab.

Comment: sure i will edit my question

Comment: could you print out the innerHTML attribute of the element instead? There is nothing wrong with your script, so I just try to figure out what is happening.